# add multiple child with one as default in html

Tags: javascript

add multiple child with one as default in html select items while querying frm localStorage.

```
for (let i in jsonObj.records) {
    let option = document.createElement("OPTION");
    option.innerHTML = jsonObj.records[i].name;
    option.value = jsonObj.records[i].unique;
    if(jsonObj.records[i].assignee == data) {

        option.selected = "select";
        // is this the correct appproach
    }
    dropDown.appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: this code is not working.c I want to add that as default item selected. But it isn't working.

Comment: try option.setAttribute("selected", true);

Comment: Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected attribute should be set to true

Your code is functionally correct. but accessing dom in every for loop causes performance issues.

Instead , create a document fragment , add all elements to fragment.
Then access dom once and add fragment

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (let i in jsonObj.records) {
let option = document.createElement("OPTION");
option.innerHTML = jsonObj.records[i].name;
option.value = jsonObj.records[i].unique;
if(jsonObj.records[i].assignee == data) {

    option.selected = true;
    // is this the correct appproach
}
fragment.appendChild(option);
}
dropDown.appendChild(fragment);
```

reference :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment